# Floating list view items

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am looking to do something like this:

[image]

I am thinking it is a ListView, with a shaded background, and the listViews items have margins spacing them apart from eachother and the edges of the screen.

Am I on the right track? or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can use paddings and margins for your list items.

Comment: Yes, and to add to Karakuri's comment, you're going to need an extra layout wrapping your list items' views with the desired padding (instead of margins on the container) since the AbsListView.LayoutParams (which your root list item view would be using) doesn't actually support the margins itself.

Answer (score 1):

Those are usually known as **Cards** in Android. They're basically just layouts with a drop shadow, but there are some libraries to ease implementation, such as [Gabriele Marotti's CardsLib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib).

Also, the new "L" Developer Preview for Android includes this widget as a first-class citizen ([`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#cardview)), since it's quite prominent in the recently unveiled "Material Design". It's also available as part of the Support Library for older versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/button_default"> // here set your shaded background

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello stackoverflow"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="25"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="Wrd"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```